# WordPress Custom Post Titles

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for a method to change how a post title is shown on screen in WordPress that only applies to the post header.

I am trying to display Name, Gender, Age in the post title. The name I display is the current post title, and I am trying to add gender and age to this for display purposes only.

I have used the current code, but it applies to everything in my theme that uses the tile, and adds these fields to menu items as well.
I have not edited any of the PHP files within the theme, and would like to avoid that and do it via a function

Here is my code:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', function( $title ) {
$gender = get_field('gender');
$dob = get_field('date_of_birth');
$birthday = new DateTime($dob);
$interval = $birthday->diff(new DateTime);
if ('babysitters' == get_post_type()) {

$temp_title = $title;

$bbstitle = $temp_title .', ' .$gender .', ' .$interval->y;
 return $bbstitle;  
} 
 return $title;

} );
```

What am I doing where it replaces all titles with these appended fields, and not just the post header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
add_filter('the_title', 'new_title', 10, 2);
function new_title($title, $id) {
    if('babysitters' == get_post_type($id)){
        $gender = get_field('gender');
        $dob = get_field('date_of_birth');
        $birthday = new DateTime($dob);
        $interval = $birthday->diff(new DateTime);
        $newtitle = $title .', ' .$gender .', ' .$interval->y;

    }
    else{

        $newtitle = $title;
    }
    return $newtitle;
}
?>
```

Comment: This one worked, looks like I missed out checking by the post id!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

```
function text_domain_custom_title($title) {
    global $post;

    if ($post->post_type == 'babysitters') {
        $gender = get_field('gender', $post->ID);
        $dob = get_field('date_of_birth', $post->ID);
        $birthday = new DateTime($dob);
        $interval = $birthday->diff(new DateTime);

        $bbstitle = $title . ', ' . $gender . ', ' . $interval->y;
        return $bbstitle;
    } else {
        return $title;
    }
}

add_filter('the_title', 'text_domain_custom_title', 10, 2);
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Please note: This code is not tested, but it should work.

---

Reference:

- [get_field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)
- [How to append text to title of Custom Post Type post (without affecting all titles on page)?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/59466/103815)

Comment: This one didn't work, as the menu items in my theme would no longer render.

Comment: @BrettCanfield: I have updated my code, check this, it 'll work.